# Is it possible to generate JAVA doc with source inside the document as well?

Tags: java, hyperlink, javadoc, documentation-generation

By default, Javadoc does not put source in its generated html files.

I would like to know whether is it possible to put the source file inside, or hyperlinked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the `javadoc` tool, it has a [-linksource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#linksource) option that seems to do what you want.